# Drag image tag on top of another, save and upload with carrierwave

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, carrierwave

I'm developing an online store where users can customize their own shirts. I'm currently using jquery for users to drag their logo on top of the shirt to preview it. How do I upload that preview using carrierwave?

Comment: are you using a canvas? you can get the base64 coding for that and send it, decode the base64 string to a file and save it using carrierwave

Comment: Look into using active storage possible